# From Spivak (Foundations)(2nd edition)

Tags: calculus, functions

I just finished high school and started reading Spivak's calculus. I've noticed that "this kind of mathematics" is kind of different and more severe from what I've been taught in high school.

> Which conditions should $f$, $g$, $h$, and $k$ satisfy so that $f(x)g(y)=h(x)k(y)$ for every $x$ and $y$?

Some hint would be useful. I've found when the equation holds, but then, when I saw the solution, I didn't understand it very well.

Comment: If you provide a little more context (what are the domains of the functions, what part of the solution puzzles you?) you may get more useful answers on this site.

Comment: i assume the domain is R ( it doesn't say anything about it, though). I actually having a hard time understanding the whole solution besides the 1st line which says when it holds ( that's pretty easy to find)...I was wondering what kind of approaches there are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that $f, g, h, k:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$, although it is unclear from Spivak's text whether this is meant.

First, if there exists $x_0$ such that neither $f(x_0)$ nor $h(x_0)$ is zero, then 
$\frac{f(x_0)}{h(x_0)}=\frac{k(y)}{g(y)} $ for all y such that neither $k(y)$ nor $g(y)$ is zero (obviously, either both functions of y are zero or neither is zero). Letting $\frac{f(x_0)}{h(x_0)}=c$, we have $k(y)=c\times g(y)$. We immediately have $f(x)=c \times h(x)$, for all $x$ such that neither $f(x)$ nor $h(x)$ is zero.

If $f(x)$ is constant and zero, then either $h(x)$ is constant and zero or $k(y)$ is constant and zero.

I will leave you to tidy up the final answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the solution in Spivak and haven't solved the problem. Since your comment asks for how one might approach the problem, here's where I'd begin: assuming things are never $0$ (a possibility I'd postpone addressing) I'd write
$$
\frac{f(x)}{h(x)} = \frac{k(y)}{g(y)} .
$$
to separate $x$ and $y$.

Then both sides of that equation must be the same constant. How far does that get you?

Comment: Thanks for answer. Well, i had separated them as you indicate. Spivak is saying the same thing that both sides must be the same constant ( I think that's very logical but i want to explain why they must be the same constant) now i saw the other answers..

Answer (score 0):

Choose arbitrary $x$ and $y$, then one solution is either $f(x)=h(x)=0$ or $g(y)=k(y)=0$. Then the other two function values are arbitrary.

If not, then WLOG, let $f(x) \ne 0$, we have
$$g(y)=\frac{h(x)}{f(x)}k(y)$$

Now if $k(y)=0$, then $g(y)=0$, which reduces to the first case, so assume $k(y) \ne 0$, then 
$$\frac{h(x)}{f(x)}=\frac{g(y)}{k(y)}$$

Fixing $x$ in the above argument, the above equation is true for all $y$ where $k(y) \ne 0$, and hence
$$\frac{g(y)}{k(y)}=\text{Constant}$$

Similarly, repeating the argument with $x,y$ switched, we can argue that
$$\frac{h(x)}{f(x)}=\text{Constant}$$

Since
$$\frac{h(x)}{f(x)}=\frac{g(y)}{k(y)}$$
the two constants should be the same.

In conclusion, the answer is

(1) $f(x)=h(x)=0$ or $g(y)=k(y)=0$

(2) $h(x)=Cf(x), g(y)=Ck(y)$ where $C\ne 0$.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Spivak actually renamed the variables and i didn't see why...yours is fairly better

Comment: I have on more question. Are functions "behave" like numbers?I see it clearly now how easy this problem was...Furthermore is it necessary to separate x and y? could we solve it differently?

Comment: @KostasT Functions and numbers are different concepts. Well, we have 4 slightly different answers here, but it seems that separating $x$ and $y$ is necessary in all answers.

Comment: thanks for answer. I know that are different :) . But why the constant must be the same? if there were 2 different constants due to our different variables x,y.....

Comment: alright...in this case there is only one set of (x,y) ? what does it mean hold one of x,y fixes why we do this?..im really sorry for the dumb questions but im trying to understand this problem deeply

Comment: I see your point. I will edit my answer.

Comment: i got it now..the fractions are Constant for a specific x and specific y right? and we say that the constant is the same cause of the equality right?

Comment: The fraction is constant for all $(x,y)$, where neither $f(x)=h(x)=0$ nor $g(y)=k(y)=0$.

Comment: got it...it's been given to us that the equality is true and equals to a C...

Answer (score 0):

The subtly lies with the value $0$. Suppose that either

$1.$ One of $g,f$ is the zero function.

and

$2$. One of $h$, $k$ is the zero function.

Then the equation clearly holds.

Now, if the above two conditions do not hold, then there is some pair $(x,y)$ we can plug in so that *one* of the sides is non-zero which implies that *none* of the functions on *either* side are the zero function.

As this has been established, fix $y$ such that one of $g(y),k(y)$ is non-zero . It's easy to see now that for this fixed $y$, *neither* $g$ nor $k$ can be $0$ (this follows from the fact that the two functions of $x$ are sometimes non-zero, so as $x$ varies one side of the equation will take non-zero values) and we thus conclude that $h(x) = c_1 \cdot f(x)$.

Fix $x$ in an analogous manner and conclude $g(y) = c_1 \cdot k(y)$. To show that the constants are equal, note that our "fixing" of the constants, as discussed in the second paragraph, is such that we don't have to worry about division by zero. Then it's straightforward division.

Comment: Are the constants equal? Two answers above the constant is C for both expressions...

Comment: @KostasT Yeah, you're right, they are equal.